# No provider for AngularFireAuth

Tags: firebase, angularfire, ionic4

I am using Ionic4 and @angular/fire to code an chat application, but I'm getting a white page and error message(F12) when I run my application.
Can someone help me ?

thank you.

app.module.ts

```js
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environments/environment';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from '@Angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
// import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireAuth

ERROR (F12) with Chrome

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

When I go to the home page it works, it is only when i go to my login page

thanks alot to those who will help me

Comment: Here is the error I have in chrome console: core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFireAuth]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFireAuth]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuth!

Answer (score 2):

The error I made was in the thrid line, it is not @Angular but @angular. after changing that, everything work fine